# Pandas week business day start & end

Tags: python, pandas, calendar

I am looking for the best way to insert a date range and return a list of the dates for the start & end of each week in business days.

`pandas.date_range()` has a similar functionality which deals with Months (`BMS`) Business Day Month Start and so I was wondering if there is something similar for week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `weekmask` parameter of `bdate_range` to select only Monday and Friday

```
start = '2010-01-01'
end = '2010-02-01'

pd.bdate_range(start, end, freq='C', weekmask='Mon Fri')
#DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-04', '2010-01-08', '2010-01-11',
#               '2010-01-15', '2010-01-18', '2010-01-22', '2010-01-25',
#               '2010-01-29', '2010-02-01'],
#              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='C')
```